# In SASS, is it possible to match the value of a child element's rule to the parent element's rule?

Tags: css, sass, parent-child

Let's say you want to have few of `h2`'s and they're all different colors, and they all have an `:after` element that is the same color.

[image: example of a styled h2]

What'd I'd like to do is match the `background-color` of each `:after` element to its parent `h2`'s `color`. Since they are both using a color attribute, it should be valid in this case.

We know that you can nest a child element in SASS like so:

```
h2{
    font-weight: bold;
    &:after{
        height:4px;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to match a value for a child's rule to the value of a parent's rule? Something like so? If there is, what is the proper syntax? I can't seem to find anything that points to an answer.

```
h2{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #093261;

    &:after{
        height:4px;
        width:50px;
        content:'';
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;

        /* this is what I'm trying to accomplish: */
        background: &:color
    }
}
```

Comment: In Stylus there is a feature called [Property Lookup](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/variables.html#property-lookup)  that I think is what you want to do but in SASS there isn´t something similar.

Comment: Would be a cool feature to add to Sass, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using either a SASS variable or an `@extend` so:

```
$headercolor: #093261;

h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $headercolor;

    &:after{
        height:4px;
        width:50px;
        content:'';
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;

        /* this is what I'm trying to accomplish: */
        background: &:color
        /* variable */
        background: $headercolor;
    }
}
```

or:

```
h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #093261;

    &:after{
        height:4px;
        width:50px;
        content:'';
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;

        /* this is what I'm trying to accomplish: */
        background: &:color
        /* extend */
        @extend h2;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to say is there would be a bunch of h2's, with different colors, and the :after element's background color for each should match the value of the h2's color, if it's possible. Basically, can you take the value of one property and use it for another property cross-parent/child?